# Suggestions for binary time-series-classification model for small dataset

Tags: classification, time-series, binary-classification, sparse

Hopefully I´m at the right place for my question:

I´m looking for suggestions for models to use to classify multivariate time series. I´m trying to find a way of classifying the behaviour of motors into "good" or "bad" based on current measurments.

I found many possible examples (as found for example in the library sktime) to use, but my biggest problem is that the dataset I have captured is incredibly small because of difficulties in the testing environment. The dataset consist of:

- 11 full time series of ~2min length
- a maximum of 12 measured variables for each time series; mainly motor currents

I therefore understand, that a valid classification is probably impossible. Maybe there are models with uncertainty though, that I could use and improve, once I generate more data in the future. Hopefully the uncertainty decreases with more data. That would be a good starting point and the best I can make of the sparse dataset, I believe.

As I understand, Bayesian Classifiers would be similar to what I´m looking for, but they aren´t specific for time series, right?

Any buzzword to look for or model suggestion?